# Exclute/ignore parameter in image's ImageUrl but still show it within a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, image, repeater

I have an image control inside a repeater. I would like to exclude/ignore a parameter in the imageurl property, because the path(source image) do not have this parameter in the name, but I still want to show the parameter in url. And I can't rename all the images, as there are a lot. Hope it make sense.

Here is an example.

It is for SEO. Original path

- /product/0001_100_00_KK00_F02.png

What I want to show in imageurl

- /product/0001_100_00_KK00_F02.png/Tv-Sony-lcd-black-bravia-KDL-26V4500

OR

- /product/0001_100_00_KK00_F02/Tv-Sony-lcd-black-bravia-KDL-26V4500.png

> ```
>     <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
>         <ItemTemplate>
>             <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' runat="server" />
>         </ItemTemplate>
>     </asp:Repeater>
> ```

And codebehind

> ```
>     rptImages.DataSource = Images.Select(s => new { Url = s });
>     rptImages.DataBind();
> ```

This works fine for the original path. But when I add `/Tv-Sony-lcd-black-bravia-KDL-26V45000` to the end of url the images is not found(of course).

So how do I add an extra parameter to the imageurl, but get the image control to ignore this and still find the image path?

Does anyone have any ideas of how to resolve this problem

Comment: The image control doesn't _find_ the image, it just outputs the URL you request it to. Whether the image can be found or not is a question of how your web server responds to the request for the image URL in question by the client browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive that with URL rewriting. Add global.asax file to your project and use some kind of rewriting logic like this.

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentPath;
    currentPath = Request.Path; // /product/0001_100_00_KK00_F02.png/Tv-Sony-lcd-black-bravia-KDL-26V4500
    if (currentPath.IndexOf(".png") > -1)
    {
        string[] paths = currentPath.Split('/');
        currentPath = currentPath.Replace("/" + paths[paths.Length - 1], ""); // /product/0001_100_00_KK00_F02.png
        Context.RewritePath(currentPath);
    }
}
```

This will work but will also rewrite all request.paths which contains".png" because of "if (currentPath.IndexOf(".png") > -1)"
It is safer to include few more conditioning.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick reply. :)

Both solutions seems to work just fine for my purpose so far. 

Now in testing mode..

Answer (score 0):

Would a URL like this work?

/product/0001_100_00_KK00_F02.png?Tv-Sony-lcd-black-bravia-KDL-26V4500

As long as you put a question mark after the file name, your image will display just fine.  As @Jon Edgerton points out, IIS is not finding your image and that is why it doesn't display.

If you want a completely custom URL, then you are going to have to do some URL re-writing.  Here is an article on that: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/517/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms/.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick reply. :)

Both solutions seems to work just fine for my purpose so far. 

Now in testing mode..

Comment: Make sure you accept an answer and vote up the answers that are helpful.